# c# draw - Add random lines in a image

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I have an image which I just want to add some random lines in.
I am not so familiar with c# draw features.

Is there any simple way to add somewhere between 4-7 different length lines different places in an already bitmap object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // calculate line start and end point here using the Random class:
    int x0 = rnd.Next(0, bitmap.Width);
    int y0 = rnd.Next(0, bitmap.Height);
    int x1 = rnd.Next(0, bitmap.Width);
    int y1 = rnd.Next(0, bitmap.Height);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, x0, y0, x1, x1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Graphics.FromBitMap does not exist, but Graphics.FromImage() does.

Comment: Also, I suppose n = lines?

Comment: Can u paste the snippet as a method called with a bitmap object? I have some difficulties assuming too many things :(

Comment: @codingjoe: Just put the whole thing into a method:  
`void DrawLinesToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
/* code here */
}

Comment: @codingjoe: x0 and y0 are the start point coordinates of the line, x1, y1 are the end coordinates.

Comment: ahh, I see your updated codesnippet now...I will try that now :)

Comment: g.DrawLine(Pens.White, x0, y0, x1, y1); // The last coordinate I believe :)